# Oscilloscope Signal Probing

Tags: oscilloscope

I am using active differential solder-on N5382A Keysight Probe and found voltage drops on the signal. Is it caused by open drain signal. It is working fine with passive probes. The signal being tested is 3.3V DC. Any explanation in detail will be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: YH CasperL - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as the Stack Exchange rules differ from typical forums. (b) Please [edit] your question, add photos (use Ctrl+G or click the "mountain image" icon to upload, max 2MB each) showing your physical probe usage in both cases. (c) Please upload the relevant part of the schematic and mark where the probes are being attached. (d) Please explain why you suspect the cause is an open-drain signal. || Although you know all the context and history, site members here are starting from scratch - so please add *all* relevant info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the datasheet, many diff probes (I could no find N5382A specifically)  are 50kOhms electrode-to-ground and 25kOhms electrode-to-electrode.

Using the common 10kOhms as pullup resistor, you should expect a very significant voltage drop when connecting the differential pair. The (10k?) pullup and the 25k electrodes form a resistor divider.

Comment: Thanks for the help.